# ::before ::after alternative(s) to display text/characters for different layouts

Tags: html, css, layout, pseudo-element

```css
p {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.line.inline_layout .character {
  font-variant-caps: small-caps
}
.line.inline_layout .stage_direction {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #333;
}
.line.inline_layout .stage_direction::before {
  content:", "
}
.line.inline_layout .stage_direction::after {
  content:" – "
}
.line.screenplay_layout {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Courier;
}
.line.screenplay_layout .character {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:block;
}
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:block;
}
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction::before {
  content:"("
}
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction::after {
  content:")"
}
```

```html
<p>Inline layout :</p>
<div class="line inline_layout">
  <span class="character">Mike</span><!--
  --><span class="stage_direction">whispering</span>
  <span class="sentence">Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>

<p>Screenplay layout :</p>
<div class="line screenplay_layout">
  <span class="character">Mike</span>
  <span class="stage_direction">whispering</span>
  <span class="sentence">Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>
```

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="line">
  <span class="character">Mike</span>
  <span class="stage_direction">whispering</span>
  <span class="sentence">Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>
```

And I have two ways to display it, depending on user's choice (see snippet), there are 4 layouts and user should be able to switch whenever he/she wants.

It worked great until I had to allow user to copy/paste and print the text.

Because I need the ::before and ::after elements to be copied as well (I know they're not actual content).

So is there a workaround to perform that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 possible layouts, your best bet is probably to use Javascript and drop pseudo elements.

Let's say your user can choose the layout of his choice with elements inside a class "selector", and your default style is "inline". Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="selector">
  <a id="inline">inline</a>
  <a id="screenplay">screenplay</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="script inline">
  <p class="character">Mike</p>
  <p class="stage_direction"><span>(</span>whispering<span>)</span></p>
  <p class="sentence">Watch out ! He's sleeping !</p>
</div>
```

By clicking on the selector, you change your script div class with the following code:

```
document.querySelector(".selector").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var itemClicked = e.target;
  // Get the new class stored in ID of element (you may use data attribute instead)
  var scriptClass = itemClicked.id;
  var script = document.querySelector(".script");
  // Reset your class to script alone
  script.className = "script";
  // Add the new class
  script.classList.add(scriptClass);
});
```

You can then decide to style, show or hide elements, depending on the class selected. Example of what your CSS would look like:

```
.selector a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.script.inline {
  font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.script.inline p {
  display: inline;
}
.script.inline .stage_direction span {
  display: none;
}
.script.screenplay {
  font-family:courier, courier new, serif;
}
.script.screenplay .stage_direction {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5c4udr8j/1/

Comment: Hmm, nice idea. But it means a lot of extra `span`s ! Which are generated via `createElement` with other complex stuffs. But I'll try to find an easy way to implement your solution :) thanks !

Comment: No. The spans don't get created with JavaScript. They're in your initial HTML and your CSS shows them or hides them depending on the layout selected by the user. JavaScript only changes the class of your class "script" or whatever you want to call it. Read the code again.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the solution you posted. You repeat the same code 6 times, which is not good practice. Also, your original question states that the user should be able to switch from a layout to another. Your solution doesn't allow that. But if that works for you, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

With Will's answer, I found a solution but without any need of JavaScript.

See snippet.

Thanks Will !

```css
.sentence span, .stage_direction span {
  display : none
}

p {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #0a0
}

.line.inline_layout .character {
  font-variant-caps: small-caps
}
.line.inline_layout:first-letter,
.line.classic_layout .character,
.line.screenplay_layout .character,
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.line.inline_layout .stage_direction, .line.classic_layout .stage_direction {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #333;
}
.line.inline_layout .stage_direction span:first-child,
.line.inline_layout .character + .sentence span,
.line.inline_layout .stage_direction + .sentence span:nth-child(2),
.line.classic_layout .stage_direction span:first-child,
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction span:nth-last-child(-n+2)
{
  display: inline;
}
.line.classic_layout, 
.line.screenplay_layout .character, 
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction {
  text-align: center;
}
.line.classic_layout .sentence {
  text-align: left
}
.line.screenplay_layout {
  font-family: Courier;
}
.line.classic_layout .sentence,
.line.screenplay_layout .stage_direction, 
.line.screenplay_layout .sentence,
.line.screenplay_layout .character {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<p>INLINE PLAY with stage direction</p>
<div class="line inline_layout">
   <span class="character">mike</span><!--
--><span class="stage_direction"><span>, </span><span>(</span>whispering<span>)</span></span><!--
--><span class="sentence"><span>.</span><span> – </span>Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>

<p>INLINE PLAY without stage direction</p>
<div class="line inline_layout">
   <span class="character">mike</span><!--
--><span class="sentence"><span>.</span><span> – </span>Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>
<hr/>
<p>CLASSIC PLAY with stage direction</p>
<div class="line classic_layout">
   <span class="character">mike</span><!--
--><span class="stage_direction"><span>, </span><span>(</span>whispering<span>)</span></span><!--
--><span class="sentence"><span>.</span><span> – </span>Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>

<p>CLASSIC PLAY without stage direction</p>
<div class="line classic_layout">
   <span class="character">mike</span><!--
--><span class="sentence"><span>.</span><span> – </span>Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>
<hr/>


<p>SCREENPLAY with stage direction</p>
<div class="line screenplay_layout">
   <span class="character">mike</span><!--
--><span class="stage_direction"><span>, </span><span>(</span>whispering<span>)</span></span><!--
--><span class="sentence"><span>.</span><span> – </span>Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>

<p>SCREENPLAY without stage direction</p>
<div class="line screenplay_layout">
   <span class="character">mike</span><!--
--><span class="sentence"><span>.</span><span> – </span>Watch out ! He's sleeping !</span>
</div>
```